# read and decode tfrecords error tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, decode, tfrecord

i convert my own grayscale dataset with 60*60 pixel to tfrecords with write_tfrecord() but when i want to read and decode them it causes error . what is the problem ?

```
train_tfrecord_addr = './data/train.tfrecords'
test_tfrecord_addr = './data/test.tfrecords'
n_train_samples = 43990
n_test_samples = 12500
batch_size = 32  # number of batches in each iteration
keep_prob = 0.5  # Dropout, probability to keep units
n_epochs = 25
tfrecords_filename = './data/test.tfrecords'


def _bytes_feature(value):
   return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


def _int64_feature(value):
   return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _float32_feature(value):
   return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))


def write_tfrecord(path):
    images_addrs, images_labels = get_lable_and_image(path=path)
    filename_pairs = list(zip(images_addrs, images_labels))
    print(filename_pairs)
    # to shuffle data
    shuffle(filename_pairs)

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_filename)

    for img_path, label in filename_pairs:
        # in this case all images are png with (32, 32) shape
        img = np.array(Image.open(img_path))  # (32, 32) uint8

        img_raw = img.tostring()
        label_raw = label.tostring()

        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
           'image_raw': _bytes_feature(img_raw),
           'label_raw': _bytes_feature(label_raw),
        }))

       writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
```

decode method ...

```
def read_and_decode(filename, batch_size, num_epochs, num_samples):
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([train_tfrecord_addr],
                                                num_epochs=num_epochs)

reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
    features={
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'label_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    })

# Convert from a scalar string tensor to a uint8 tensor
image_raw = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
image_resized = tf.reshape(image_raw, [60 * 60])

# Convert from [0, 255] -> [-0.5, 0.5] floats.
image_resized = tf.cast(image_resized, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5

# Convert from a scalar string tensor to a uint8 tensor
label_raw = tf.decode_raw(features['label_raw'], tf.uint8)
label_resized = tf.reshape(label_raw, [2])

images, labels = tf.train.batch([image_resized, label_resized],
                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                capacity=num_samples,
                                num_threads=2, )
return images, labels
```

this is the main code that feed convolutions data .

```
def run_training():
"""Train ShapeNet for a number of steps."""

# Tell TensorFlow that the model will be built into the default Graph.
with tf.Graph().as_default():

    # Input train images and labels.
    train_images, train_labels = read_and_decode(filename=train_tfrecord_addr,
                                                 batch_size=batch_size,
                                                 num_epochs=n_epochs,
                                                 num_samples=n_train_samples)
    # Input test images and labels.
    # define batch_size = all test samples
    test_images, test_labels = read_and_decode(filename=test_tfrecord_addr,
                                               batch_size=n_test_samples,
                                               num_epochs=n_epochs,
                                               num_samples=n_test_samples)

    # define placeholder for input images and labels
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 60 * 60])
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

    # Build a Graph that computes predictions from the inference model.
    prediction = convolutional_network_model(X)

    # Backpropagation
    # measure of error of our model
    # this needs to be minimised by adjusting W and b
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(prediction))

    # define training step which minimises cross entropy
    train_op =tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
              learning_rate=0.001)
              .minimize(cross_entropy)

    # argmax gives index of highest entry in vector (1st axis of 1D tensor)
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))

    # get mean of all entries in correct prediction, the higher the better
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

    # The op for initializing the variables.
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                       tf.local_variables_initializer())

    st = time.time()
    # Create a session for running operations in the Graph.
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        # Initialize the variables (the trained variables and the
        # epoch counter).
        sess.run(init_op)

        # Start input enqueue threads.
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        for epoch in range(n_epochs):
            for itr in range(n_train_samples // batch_size):
                # fetch the batch train images and labels
                batch_x, batch_y = sess.run([train_images, train_labels])
                sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})

            # fetch whole test images and labels
            batch_x, batch_y = sess.run([test_images, test_labels])

            # feed the model with all test images and labels
            acc, _ = sess.run([accuracy, train_op],
                              feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            print('epoch %d/%d: , accuracy = %.3f'
                  % (epoch, n_epochs, acc))

        # When done, ask the threads to stop.
        coord.request_stop()

        # Wait for threads to finish.
        coord.join(threads)

    et = time.time()
    duration = et - st
    print(duration)
```

this is the error . i also convert my dataset in binary format but again i see the same error

```
2018-02-13 13:53:02.401813: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-
 win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your 
 CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to 
 use: AVX
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_call
return fn(*args) File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1329, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue 
'_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 32, 
 current size 0)
 [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8], 
 timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]
 (batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "F:/project/python/MathNet/mathnet.py", line 232, in <module>
   run_training()
  File "F:/project/python/MathNet/mathnet.py", line 207, in run_training
    batch_x, batch_y = sess.run([train_images, train_labels])
 File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
  run_metadata_ptr)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1128, in _run
  feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1344, in _do_run
  options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1363, in _do_call
  raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue 
   '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 
 32, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, 
 DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1, 
  _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](batch/fifo_queue, 
   batch/n)]]

  Caused by op 'batch', defined at:
    File "F:/project/python/MathNet/mathnet.py", line 232, in <module>
    run_training()
     File "F:/project/python/MathNet/mathnet.py", line 159, in run_training
    num_samples=n_train_samples)
    File "F:/project/python/MathNet/mathnet.py", line 105, in 
read_and_decode
num_threads=2, )
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 979, in batch
name=name)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py", line 754, in _batch
dequeued = queue.dequeue_many(batch_size, name=name)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 475, in dequeue_many
self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2764, in 
_queue_dequeue_many_v2
component_types=component_types, timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
 packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in 
_apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-
access

  OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' 
  is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 32, current size 0)
   [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_UINT8], 
  timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]
  (batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]
```

Comment: What's the batch size, how many epochs have you running it for?
Also what's the size of your training set?

Comment: train.tfrehards has 43990 pics for train , test.records has 12500 pictures for test batch_size = 32

Comment: How many epochs?

Comment: It is n_epochs = 25

Comment: i also add 10 pic to train folder now i have 44000 pic but again this error appeared .

Comment: I highly recommend converting the code to use the Dataset API: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets. It is very clean and powerful and you don't have to worry about threads/queues/coordinators.

Comment: Just want to reiterate the value of the suggestion by @iga. Reading TFRecord files is a breeze with the tf.data.Dataset API. No queues, no deadlocks, no coordinators.